# How to find which line error occurs in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I get an error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" while running my app and I do not know where in the app the error has occurred.

I have two view controllers, and the error for sure doesn't occur in the first view controller because the view of the second controller appears and I also tested with break points in view will appear in the second view controller and everything works fine.

But now I do not know where to put breakpoints in the second view controller. Up to **viewDidLoad** and **viewWillAppear** everything works fine, but at the **didRecievememoryWarning** method the error comes back up again.

Do I have to place break points all over the file and find out which line is causing the error, or is there a quicker way to find out which is the exact line that is causing the error.

Comment: Xcode highlights the crashing line. You will probably already see which value is `nil` there. If you don't, use the debugger to debug what values your variables have.

Comment: Xcode just switches to the AppDelegate and shows an error message. There are no line numbers, and the crashing line is NOT highlighted, rather the AppDelegate class declaration line is highlighted. The debug navigator is stopped at `main` - not the line nor the function which caused the error. If line numbers can be provided via DSym files for apps in the Store, why can't Xcode show line numbers of errors??? Visual Studio does this for Microsoft code, and always has.

Comment: a stack trace is shown if you click on the text all the way to the right of the debugger buttons. there you'll be able to see the last method called before the error occured

Comment: If the app crashes because of an exception and Xcode stops in main: just add an exception breakpoint and set it to break at throw, and Xcode will stop at the line that actually caused the exception.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That crash should show up in the debug navigator. It shows you the instruction that caused the crash.

[image]

Comment: The debug navigator is stopped at `main`. This may be the "instruction" that caused the error, but it doesn't show which line on which the error occurred.

Comment: Same here. Xcode is extremely uninformative. Of all my experiences learning new things (web development, Android development, C#, command line usage, etc.), iOS development has been the most maddening by very large margin.